# Como añadir un RadComboBox al editar/insertar del Scheduler

Tags: vb.net, telerik

Queria saber como puedo insertar un campo `RadComboBox` en el popUp de editar/insertar del Scheluder sin tener que crear un `AdvancedInsertTemplate`.

Ahora mismo para crear un comboBox normal lo creo de esta manera en el Page_Load:

```
Dim rt As New ResourceType("Room")
        rt.DataSource = Rooms
        rt.KeyField = "RoomNo"
        rt.ForeignKeyField = "RoomNo"
        rt.TextField = "RoomName"
```

Pero quiero un `RadComboBox` para que se vayan filtrando los datos cuando el usuario escriba dentro del comboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede añadir un nuevo controlador dentro del evento `FormCreated`

```
if ((e.Container.Mode == SchedulerFormMode.AdvancedEdit) || (e.Container.Mode == SchedulerFormMode.AdvancedInsert))
{
    RadComboBox subjectChanger = new RadComboBox();
    subjectChanger.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("-"));
    subjectChanger.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Homework"));
    subjectChanger.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Test"));
    subjectChanger.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Final exam"));
    subjectChanger.Label = "Update subject:";
    subjectChanger.OnClientSelectedIndexChanging = "OnClientSelectedIndexChanging";
    RadTextBox subject = e.Container.FindControl("Subject") as RadTextBox;
    subject.ClientEvents.OnLoad = "OnLoadSubjectTextBox";
    subject.Parent.Controls.Add(subjectChanger);
}
```